# Inheritance causing errors with constructors?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I have a class called CreatureAi with the following code.

```
public class CreatureAi {
    public Creature creature;

    public CreatureAi(Creature creature) {
        this.creature = creature;
        this.creature.setCreatureAi(this);
    }
    // There's more, I'm shortening it.
```

I have a class called PlayerAi which extends it.

```
public class PlayerAi extends CreatureAi {
    private FieldOfView fov;
    private Player player;

    public PlayerAi(Player player, FieldOfView fov) {
        this.player = player;
        this.player.setCreatureAi(this);
        this.fov = fov;
    }
    // These are the only constructors.
```

However, Netbeans gives me this error.

```
constructer CreatureAi in class CreatureAi cannot be applied to the given types.
required: Creature
found: No arguements
reason: Actual and formal lists differ in length.
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: `super(creature)` in first line, you don't have  constructor with no-args in CreatureAi

Comment: @nachokk Where did I write super(creature)?

Comment: Check the Java Language reference about object construction: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write your subclass, implicit calls `super()` that is in super type constructor.

```
public PlayerAi(Player player, FieldOfView fov) {
        super(); // this call "father" constructor
        this.player = player;
        this.player.setCreatureAi(this);
        this.fov = fov;
}
```

As you show in your code , your base class doesn't have `no-arg` constructor. So your child is not valid. You have to call one valid super constructor.

```
public PlayerAi(Player player, FieldOfView fov) {
            super(//??creature); // you have to pass something here
            this.player = player;
            this.player.setCreatureAi(this);
            this.fov = fov;
    }
```

Alternative if you can modify your `CreatureAi`,  you can add default no-args constructor.

```
public class CreatureAi {
    private Creature creature;

    public CreatureAi(){}

    public CreatureAi(Creature creature) {
        this.creature = creature;
        this.creature.setCreatureAi(this);
    }
    // There's more, I'm shortening it.
```

Comment: So my child class automatically calls my parent constructor?

Comment: Basically, you need to have `super(aPlayer, aFov)` as the first instruction in `PlayerAi` constructor, or make a no-arg constructor for `CreatureAi`.

Comment: @AnubianNoob Always, that is why when you use inheritance, you say that your PlayerAi `is a` `CreatureAi`

Comment: Yes, every time a class in initialized, all parents constructor are called, in order, from `Object` to the actual class, through all the class hierarchy.

Comment: The problem is my PlayerAi uses a Player object instead of a Creature... how would you suggest I go about fixing this?

Comment: Looking at your code, and using some imagination, I guess you'd better create a common (maybe abstract) parent class for both `CreatureAi` and `PlayerAi`, and make them siblings, rather than father/child. (i.e. `AbstractAi`, `CreatureAi extends AbstractAi`, `PlayerAi extends AbstractAi`)

Comment: @GiulioFranco my CreatureAi is a parent class, and I have a PlayerAi and multiple enemy ai's under it. Should I make all the enemy ai's extend the AbstractAi?

Comment: @AnubianNoob  Make fields less modifier visibility (change `public` to `private`) if you don't have a good reason to do not.

Comment: @AnubianNoob One thing you may want to consider is making an `Ai` **interface** that both `CreatureAi` and `PlayerAi` implement instead of trying to make `PlayerAi` inherit from `CreatureAi`. I've found that I rarely use inheritance in practice, and in my opinion, my code is much cleaner because of it.

Comment: @AnubianNoob wait. `Player` also extends `Creature`, right? Then, you could remove the `player` field from `PlayerAi`, call `super(player)` in `PlayerAi`'s constructor, and remove the `this.player.setCreatureAi(this);`, since that value is already in `CreatureAi`.creature

Comment: It might be simplest for the newbie to remove the parms from the constructors and just use setters to set values, after the object is created.  Less "elegant", but easier to understand.

Comment: Also, since they're public and not final (I'd make them private and final)

Comment: I forgot to make these fields private, but I'm making them final too. That didn't occur to me.